# How to create AWS lambda function from local machine using AWS Ruby SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm having troubles creating request that will create AWS lambda function from local machine. This is the content that I'm trying to send:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

client = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')

args = {}
args[:role] = role
args[:function_name] = function_name
args[:handler] = handler
args[:runtime] = 'python2.7'
code = {}
code[:zip_file] = '/root/main.zip'
args[:code] = code

client.create_function(args)
```

Location of zip_file is ok on filesystem. I want to upload lambda content from local filesystem without using S3 (I saw there is a way to do that from S3 also).

The error I'm getting is:

```
lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.11/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again. (Aws::Lambda::Errors::InvalidParameterValueException)
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Bakir

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you've already found it out, but just for the sake of question to be answered here is what you should've done:

```rb
require 'aws-sdk'

client = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')

args = {}
args[:role] = role
args[:function_name] = function_name
args[:handler] = handler
args[:runtime] = 'python2.7'
code = {}
code[:zip_file] = File.open('main.zip', 'rb').read
args[:code] = code

client.create_function(args)
```

According to [Aws::Lambda::Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Lambda/Client.html#create_function-instance_method) docs, option `:code` is a [Types::FunctionCode](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Lambda/Types/FunctionCode.html) type, where `zip_file` is a `String. The contents of your zip file containing your deployment package.`